# How to I find the p-value for a weighted correlation?

Tags: r, correlation

Does anyone know how to get a p-value for a weighted correlation coefficient?

I used

```
wtd.cors(LepProp$x,LepProp$y,weight=LepProp$Weights)
```

to account for varying sample weights.

I also know about using `cor.test` to get the p-value but this doesn't work for the weighted version.

Comment: Have you tried wt.cor (not wt.cors), which is supposed to produce p-values?

Comment: Which package is `wtd.cors` from?

Answer (score 0):

`wtd.cor` would work as Alex Trueman suggested. But make sure that you set `collapse=FALSE` if `LepProp$x` or `LepProp$y` is a column vector containing a single variable; you would get an error otherwise.